# How reliable is Location in Login History

Tags: community, login

Recently I launched a Community for a client with customers 99.9% living in the same country (Germany). However, I've seen multiple users that logged into the community from different countries, US and Croatia are ones I've seen (as per the Location column in the Login History table). Quite a lot of people log in to the community using their phones, so that may decrease the reliability. Is this a commong thing to happen, or should I investigate further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login Location depends on IP address. You may find users that are using VPN (a Virtual Private Network), a Proxy, a Tor browser, or other such "IP Anonymizing" technology. They may also be behind some sort of configuration enforced by the network they're logging in from (e.g. a University/College network might be entirely routed through another country for some reason). As such, it is inevitable that some of your users may appear to come from other countries, even if they were truly 100% in Germany. The location is only as reliable as the IP source information.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for your reply.